# How to implement Arabic speech recognition to iOS app using iSpeech?

Tags: ios, objective-c, speech-recognition, arabic, ispeech

Now I would like to implement Arabic speech recognition and tts function to my sample app. It seems ispeech is already supporting Arabic and I have implemented Arabic tts function, but I don't know the way of implementing speech recognition of Arabic.

I guess it is necessary to know Arabic locale which is supported by iSpeech, but I am not sure.
Is there a way for this?